# Safari causing checkbox to change height and not be selected

Tags: javascript, css, forms, safari

Having an issue with Safari rendering a checkbox oddly. On my site if you select a subscription and choose "Subscribe Now" the subsequent page has the issue (don't worry, you don't need to buy anything!)

If you scroll down, in FF, Opera, IE and Edge, it displays it properly:

[image]

However in Safari we get:

[image]

The CSS is a bit hacky but shouldn't it at least work?

Secondly, it *seems* to be checked but unlike in Chrome/FF etc there's no visual representation of it being clicked i.e. no  tick/check

[image]